# Power and Resistance

Tags: electricity

Why is relation between power and resistance given by two equations,viz, $P=I^2R$ and $p=\frac{V^2}{R}$ ?

Is $P$ directly proportional to R or inversely proportional ?

Comment: ...it depends on whether you have a current source or a voltage source. In principle you only need to know that $P=I V$ and $V=R I$. From this you get the formulae you provided.

Answer (score 2):

> Is $P$ directly proportional to R or inversely proportional ?

Neither.

Having proportionality means that you have a *proportionality **constant***. Saying that $P$ is proportional or inversely proportional to $R$,

$$P\propto R\qquad\text{or}\qquad P\propto \frac1R\;,$$

implies that a proportionality **constant** ties them together:

$$P=aR\qquad\text{or}\qquad P=b\frac1R\;.$$

These $a$ and $b$ must be **constant**, otherwise we are not allowed to call it "proportional" or "inversely proportional".

So if $P$ should be proportional to $R$ in $P=I^2R$, then $I^2$ must be the proportionality **constant**. And should $P$ be inversely proportional to $R$ in $P=V^2/R$, then $V^2$ must be the proportionality **constant**.

But neither $V$ nor $I$ are independent from $R$. If you change $R$, they change as well. $R$ is involved in their expressions as well and can't be isolated.

*But $R$ on the other hand is constant (often)! So, $P$ is proportional to $I^2$ and also to $V^2$*.

That you have two different equations for power here with $R$ being in the numerator and then in the denominator, just means that the influence that $R$ has on the rest of the parameters is different in the two cases. And certainly it is: That influence is seen through Ohm's law $V=RI$, and here it is clear that increasing $R$ will *decrease* $I$ but *increase* $V$.

So when $I$ is in the numerator, $R$ must be as well to account for the reduction when $R$ changes. And when $V$ is in the numerator, $R$ must be in the denominator to account for the rise when $R$ changes.

Then you ask in a comment elsewhere:

> How will I know that I am starting with current or voltage

It doesn't matter. You can use any of them. Just use whichever you have and put them into the formula for $P$ that fits the best. Both will work and both will give the same result.

Answer (score -1):

Power is given by the equation $$P=I*V$$where $I$ is the current and $V$ is the voltage. We also know that $$V=I*R$$ or, by swapping $I$ and $V$: $$I=V/R$$ with $R$ being the resistance.

By substituting the last equation into the first we get: $$P=V^2/R$$

Substituting the second equation into the first we get $$P=I^2*R$$

In other words, the two equations are identical. In one we are calculating power from current and resistance, in the other we use voltage and resistance. Voltage and current are not independent of each other. If you change one of them, the other will change as well. Power is proportional to $R$ if you use current to calculate it, but inversely proportional if you start with voltage.

Comment: How will I know that I am starting with current or voltage

Comment: You can start with either one, the result is the same. Which one you use depends on which one you know. If you know V and R, work out P from that. The same goes if you know V & I or I & R, just use the appropriate formula.

Comment: Why the downvote?